# OpenGL - Trouble With Custom Perspective Matrix & Shader

Tags: opengl, matrix, glsl, lwjgl

This is my code for generating the perspective matrices:

```
public static Matrix4f orthographicMatrix(float left, float right, float bot, 
    float top, float far, float near) {
    // construct and return matrix
    Matrix4f mat = new Matrix4f();
    mat.m00 = 2 / (right - left);
    mat.m11 = 2 / (top - bot);
    mat.m22 = -2 / (far - near);
    mat.m30 = -((right + left) / (right - left));
    mat.m31 = -((top + bot) / (top - bot));
    mat.m32 = -((far + near) / (far - near));
    mat.m33 = 1;
    return mat;
}
public static Matrix4f projectionMatrix(float fovY, float aspect, 
    float near, float far) {
        // compute values
        float yScale = (float) ((float) 1 / Math.tan(Math.toRadians(fovY / 2)));
        float xScale = yScale / aspect;
        float zDistn = near - far;
        // construct and return matrix
        Matrix4f mat = new Matrix4f();
        mat.m00 = xScale;
        mat.m11 = yScale;
        mat.m22 = far / zDistn;
        mat.m23 = (near * far) / zDistn;
        mat.m32 = -1;
        mat.m33 = 0;
        return mat;
}
```

In my program, first a square is rendered in orthographical perspective, then a square is rendered in projection perspective.

But here's my problem - when my shader does the multiplication in this order:

```
gl_Position = mvp * vec4(vPos.xyz, 1);
```

Only the square rendered with projection perspective is displayed. But when the multiplication is done in this order:

```
gl_Position = vec4(vPos.xyz, 1) * mvp;
```

Only the square rendered with orthographical perspective is displayed! So obviously my problem is that only one square is displayed at a time given a certain multiplication order.

Comment: Issues with multiplication order are indicative of issues with the order you store the components in your matrix. `mat * vec` is equivalent to `vec * transpose (mat)`, put another way, if you are using row-major matrices (which are effectively `transpose (mat)` as far as GL is concerned) instead of column-major you need to reverse the order of your matrix multiplication. This goes for compound multiplication too, you have to reverse the entire sequence of multiplications, which is why the order of scaling, rotation and translation between D3D and OpenGL is backwards.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman That solved it - I swaped the 'xy' values in the projection matrix construction and used `gl_Position = vec4(vPos.xyz, 1) * mvp;`. Thanks alot - turn that into an answer and I will accept!

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman And you brining up the difference between OpenGL and D3D would explain why this happened - I got the projection matrix code from a D3D tutorial, and the orthographical from an OpenGL one.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Oops, that was a mistake from me copying my code into the question. I do set m33 to 1 in my actualy code.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman I haven't implemented the modelview part yet, so all I do is pass the perspective matrix into the MVP.

Comment: Are you passing `GL_TRUE` for **transpose** when you specify your matrix uniforms by chance? I know I keep saying this, but that orthographic matrix is a perfectly valid column-major matrix, it should not be behaving the way you are describing.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman This is what the function call looks like: `glUniformMatrix4(mvpUniformLoc, GL_TRUE, mvpBuffer);` Is it better I pass `GL_FALSE` and change matrices accordingly?

Comment: Yes, use `GL_FALSE` to keep your matrices column-major (`GL_TRUE` will transpose them and result in row-major). Then you can use the multiplication order I described in my answer. You don't have to use column-major matrices in GLSL, but most textbooks are written under the assumption that you are so it is best to keep with tradition. As such, you need to correct your perspective matrix function to spit out a column-major matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issues with multiplication order are indicative of issues with the order you store the components in your matrix.

`mat * vec` is equivalent to `vec * transpose (mat)`

To put this another way, if you are using row-major matrices (which are effectively `transpose (mat)` as far as GL is concerned) instead of column-major you need to reverse the order of your matrix multiplication. This goes for compound multiplication too, you have to reverse the entire sequence of multiplications. This is why the order of scaling, rotation and translation between D3D (row-major) and OpenGL (column-major) is backwards.

#### Therefore, when you construct your MVP matrix it should look like this:

`projection * view * model`  (OpenGL)

`model      * view * projection`  (Direct3D)

---

Column-major matrix multiplication, as OpenGL uses, should read right-to-left. That is, you start with an object space position (right-most) and transform to clip space (left-most).

In other words, this is the proper way to transform your vertices...

```
gl_Position =  ModelViewProjectionMatrix   * position;

~~~~~~~~~~~   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~   ~~~~~~~~~
 clip space    object space to clip space    obj space
```